# groovy RESTClient json custom serialization

Tags: json, groovy

```
class Account {
    Date dob=new Date();
}

import net.sf.json.JSON;
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient;

    def rest=new RESTClient("http://localhost:9090/Rest/rest")
    def resp=rest.post(
        contentType: "application/json",
        body: account
        )
```

the JSON content is formed as

```
{"dob":{"date":19,"day":1,"hours":17,"minutes":34,"month":4,"seconds":44,"time":1400501084326,"timezoneOffset":-330,"year":114}}
```

How to override JSON serializer for Date  <-> Long(getTime())

Answer (score 1):

It is little bit late and I think that is not the cleanest, but I hope it helps.

It is necesary to replace the "EncoderRegistry" with your own JSON parser.

```
RESTClient restClient = new RESTClient( "http://myrest.com")
EncoderRegistry encoderRegistry = restClient.getEncoder();
encoderRegistry.putAt(groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON, {it ->
    def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder();
    builder.content = it
    ByteArrayInputStream dataStreamed = new ByteArrayInputStream(builder.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    InputStreamEntity res = new InputStreamEntity(dataStreamed);
    res.setContentType(groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON.toString())
    res;
})
```

Using JsonBuilder instead of the default of the rest client it use a standar format to send the date: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+.sTZD

Then you can use the restClient as usual:

```
 def response = restClient.post(
            path: path,
            headers: ["User-Agent": "UserAgent"],
            query: query,
            body: body,
            requestContentType: groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON
    )
```

Btw, if you want to replace the parser you need to replace the "ParserRegistry"

```
 ParserRegistry parserRegistry = restClient.getParser()     
 parserRegistry.putAt(groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON,{HttpResponseDecorator resp ->
        def obj = null
        if (resp.status ==200){
            if(clazz != null){
                String jsonString = IOUtils.toString(resp.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");
                obj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString,new TypeReference<MyObject>(){});
            }
            return obj
        }else{
            throw new Exception("No found")
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Some variations on [Iñaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6440407/i%C3%B1aki)'s answer.

Example of replacing the default JSON encoder with JsonGenerator.

```
def generator = new groovy.json.JsonGenerator.Options()
    .excludeNulls()
    .addConverter(Instant) { Instant i ->
        i.toEpochMilli()
    }
    .build()

restClient.getEncoder().putAt(groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON, {body ->
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(generator.toJson(body))
    entity.setContentType( groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON.toString() )
    return entity
})
```

Example of replacing the both the JSON encoder and parser with ObjectMapper:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS)
objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS)

restClient.getEncoder().putAt(groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON, {body ->
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(body))
    entity.setContentType( groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON.toString() )
    return entity
})

restClient.getParser().putAt(JSON, { resp ->
    return objectMapper.readValue(resp.entity.content, YourPojo.class)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the brightest solution, but you can get the properties map from the account object and change the `date` key:

```
import net.sf.json.*

class Account {
  Date date = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", '2014-05-01')
  String name
}

a = new Account(name: 'john doe')

aMap = a.properties

aMap.date = aMap.date.time

json = JSONObject.fromObject(aMap)

assert json.toString() == '{"date":1398913200000,"name":"john doe"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the marshaller in the Bootstrap file for example:

```
   class BootStrap {

    def init = {
        servletContext ->

        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Date) {

            return it.time
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mine is not grails application,its JSF app with some spring services written in groovy